# TypeError: this.prototype is undefined when calling Function.prototype.method()

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I am reading the book "Javascript: The good parts".
Now I am reading chapter about Augmenting Types:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
   this.prototype[name] = func;
   return this;
};
```

**UPDATE:**
Why following code does not work?

```
js> Function.prototype.method("test", function(){print("TEST")});
typein:2: TypeError: this.prototype is undefined
```

But following code works without problems:

```
js> Function.method("test", function(){print("TEST")});
function Function() {[native code]}
```

Why this code works?

```
js> var obj = {"status" : "ST"};
js> typeof obj;
"object"
js> obj.method = function(){print(this.status)};
(function () {print(this.status);})
js> obj.method();
ST
```

"obj" is object.
But I can call method "method" on it.
What is the difference between Function.prototype.method and obj.method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` refers to `Function.prototype` because you called `.method` on that. So, you're using `Function.prototype.prototype` which does not exist.

Either use `Function.method(...)` or `this[name] = ...` to eliminate one of the `.prototype`s.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand. I did not pay attention on following line this.prototype[name] = func;

Answer (score 5):

Because:

```
Function instanceof Function           // <--- is true
Function.prototype instanceof Function // <-- is false
```

- `Function.prototype` is an Object, and does not inherit anything from the Function contructor.
- `Function` is a constructor, but also a function, so it inherits methods from `Function.prototype`.
- When calling `Function.method`, you're calling the `method` method of an instance of `Function`. So, `this` points to the created instance of `Function`.
- When calling `Function.prototype.method`, you're invoking an ordinary method of an object. `this` points to `Function.prototype`.

To clarify, here's an example:

```
Function.method()                // is equivalent to
(function Function(){}).method()
(new Function).method()          // Because Function is also a function

Function.prototype.method // No instance, just a plain function call
```

Comment: "When calling `Function.prototype.method`, you're invoking an ordinary function. `this` points to undefined (strict mode) or `window`." - this is not correct. It points to the object that you're calling it on; in this case, `Function.prototype`.

Comment: @pimvdb So what's the difference between object Function.prototype and object obj from my question?

Comment: @VladimirBezugliy When calling `Function.prototype.method()`, this points to an object, which doesn't have a `prototype` property. Type this in your REPL: `({}).prototype`. The return value will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

prototype is only used when you are declaring the function, but not when you are calling it. Prototype makes the function a member of the object that gets created with every instance of that object.