# No "Function.method" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

I am reading the book by Douglas Crockford, and he uses the construct of

```
Function.method('inherits', function(Parent){
   this.prototype=new Parent();
   return this;
});
```

If we leave alone the meaning of it, I simply can't get around the syntax. I try to run it in chrome, and get

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function test3.html:18
(anonymous function)
```

as also happens with if I try (**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alex440/yFhTX/)**)

```
Function.method("test", function () { return "TEST"; });
```

There seems to be a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199344/typeerror-this-prototype-is-undefined-when-calling-function-prototype-method/9199446#9199446) which says this line is working, but I can't make it work. Why can it be?

Comment: `Function.method` isn't a built-in JavaScript function.  It's something he made up: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html#sugar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that line is working in [the post you refer to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199344/typeerror-this-prototype-is-undefined-when-calling-function-prototype-method/9199446) is because `Function.prototype` has been extended with the method:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
   this.prototype[name] = func;
   return this;
};
```

If you run the above code and only then run the code you have, everything will work - or you can just change `.method` to `.prototype[name_here] =` and everything will work the same.

#### A note on best practices

If you are going to extend prototypes in this day and age it is better to use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to ensure that the method is not enumerable.